# PM2 Similar for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, process, pm2

Tomcat due to auto-of-memory or rare problem it stops, and needs to manually start the service back.   Is there any simple Process manager like PM2 for Tomcat, to monitor and start when not running.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of analysis, found Monit is good alternative for PM2 and it has Web access too.